# $(Build.BuildId) not replacing in terraform tf file in Azure build pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am using terraform files with the .net core 2.1 project. I am trying to put a revision number in one of the terraform file and the revision number would be replace with the Build.BuildId of Azure pipeline.

Build.BuildId is predefined variable in Azure pipeline.

I tried a lot but It is not working.

Comment: Could you share more details what you tried?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Terraform documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/environment-variables.html#tf_var_name), we have to create environment variables named TF_VAR_x for Terraform to automatically pick them up.

Another option is to pass the variable value in to the Terraform script by specifying `-var 'BuildId=$(Build.BuildId)'` on the command line